# Sending javaMail attachement from database records

Tags: java, mysql, grails, jakarta-mail, email-attachments

In database table I have 3 byte array fields which hold sqlType longblob (jpg, png, gif). How to implement logic for sending these files with javaMail as attachements? I'm only interested in making attachments with these files not the rest of mail logic. I understand how to send attachments from files, but how to do it from database?

```
...
byte [] picture1
byte [] picture2
byte [] picture3
...
static mapping = {
    picture1 column:"picture1", sqlType: "longblob"
    picture2 column:"picture2", sqlType: "longblob"
    picture3 column:"picture3", sqlType: "longblob"
}
...
```

EDIT: I tried to pass an image file to my sendMail method. Specificaly, I passed it to ByteArrayDataSource. When Is there a way to make this work for more than one format, or do I need to do some 'hacking'? I guess I could make extra field in database where I would save file extension, and when I want to retrieve the image from database for sending it in attachment I would pass it to my sendMail method acompanied with extension. And in the sendMail method I would have switch statement that will determine the contentType for ByteArrayDataSource. But I'm wondering if there is more elegant way. This is my code:

```
        MimeBodyPart messagePart = new MimeBodyPart();
        messagePart.setText(msgText);
        MimeBodyPart attachmentPart = new MimeBodyPart();
        ByteArrayDataSource attPic1 = new ByteArrayDataSource(p1, "image/jpeg");        


        attachmentPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(attPic1));
        attachmentPart.setFileName(attPic1.getName());

        Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();

        multipart.addBodyPart(messagePart);

        multipart.addBodyPart(attachmentPart);
```

...

Answer (score 2):

You should read a byte array data (picture) from database and then use http://javamail.kenai.com/nonav/javadocs/javax/mail/util/ByteArrayDataSource.html to create a data source for attachement using your byte array and setting mime type.